# Failed to deploy application 'HelloWorld' to MobileFirst Server: : HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Unable to deploy applications to mobile first server. I'm using eclipse MARS with Java 7 on a mac with the default configuration.

Comment: Are there any error messages from the console you can post? What version of Worklight/MobileFirst Platform are you using? Make sure you have the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers installed.

See the support matrix for supported versions of eclipse: http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=4DB072503A2F11E396F9FC10E99BE807&osPlatforms=AIX%7CLinux%7CMac%20OS%7CMobile%20OS%7CSolaris%7CWindows&duComponentIds=D001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3/7.0 does not support Eclipse Mars at this time.

Try again with Eclipse Java EE Kepler or Luna, which are the supported versions of Eclipse.